# Cursor disappear when I get close to the top of the screen

Tags: cursor

The title describes the issue perfectly. It happens in linux mint Rafaela too..and it didnt happen with the live USB. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem appears when we change the driver from X.Org driver to the proprietary driver. Going back to the originally installed VGA driver solves the problem.